# Can't integrate Dialogflow with Google Assistant after importing from zip

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I just exported Dialogflow action/agent from one account and imported to the other as zip. The import was successful and the commands are working fine, but I cant seem to be able to integrate it with Google Assistant. I did try to change the agent/action and the google action invocation name in the previous account but to no avail

[selected test from integration panel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/83SJ5.png)

[the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NjIuj.png)

Edit: I worked after a day o.O

Comment: That seems to be a case for the support

Comment: yeah. deleted everything before trying again and still same

Comment: I'm assuming this is with the agent deployed (be it via Firebase or from the Dialogflow console's Fulfillment section)?

Answer (score 1):

Try opening the action on google simulator and then publish the app.